# Postgres connection not established after abnormal reboot

Tags: postgresql, osx-mavericks

After a memory freeze of the unit running postgresql, upon restart the connections cannot be established as

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

A rails application can generate a `tmp/pid/server.pid` file, confirms no connections are established.  Now a manual restart with

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.5  -l /usr/local/var/postgres@9.5/server.log start

pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting
$ /bin/sh: /usr/local/var/postgres@9.5/server.log: No such file or directory
```

then hangs there without returning a prompt.  `control-c` needs to be invoked to get the prompt back.  Further:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.5 stop
waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

directory `/usr/local/var/postgresql@9.5` contains a `postgresql.conf` file although it is entirely populated by commented out lines.

I also noted that directory /usr/local/var/log has two files `postgres.log` and `postgresql@9.5.log`  which are timestamped to the current minute (which is consistent with the notion of server running). The logs are **huge**  possibly being at the root of the problem in the first place.

What is the best way to reset to reset the log files and get postgresql running properly?

Comment: Look at the last few dozen lines of the huge log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two elements seemed to be at play here.

1 - homebrew which does not support this version of the OS which was broken and had its own process `homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` for an installation that never could complete.

2 - a second postgresql plist process from manual installation of postgresql  `/Users/mainuser/Library/LaunchAgents` with the properly running db.

The hard reboot launched both leading to a confused situation.

Removal of the unwanted plist and restarting made postgresql available anew.